# Compare two files based on the values in their last column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files, each of them have several columns and not equal in line number , I need to read the third column in both files and make sure are identical then compare the forth column in both files and get the highest number and print whole line in a third file. and the for the line which not found in the other file take it also as highest number

**File A**

```
a b c 10
d e f 11
g h i 15
j k l 15
p l m 35
```

**Flie B**

```
d e f 15
j k l 20
w x z 40
```

Required Output

**File C**

```
a b c 10
d e f 15
g h i 15
j k l 20
p l m 35
w x z 40
```

Comment: If you know `awk`, this is a simple task.

Comment: I am beginner I know awk but I do not how to do it if can help me much appreciate you

Comment: What about column 1 and 2, do you ignore them (show in example).

Comment: yes ignore them

Comment: I am sorry for this confusion, I wish it is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat fileA fileB | sort -k3,3 -k4,4nr | sort -k3,3 -u
a b c 10
d e f 15
g h i 15
j k l 20
p l m 35
w x z 40
```

This is a pipeline with three parts:

1. Concatenate `fileA` with `fileB`.
2. Sort the concatenated file in decreasing numerical order based on the fourth column for each unique value in the third column. The result of this step is

   ```
   a b c 10
   d e f 15
   d e f 11
   g h i 15
   j k l 20
   j k l 15
   p l m 35
   w x z 40
   ```
3. Sort this again, but remove duplicates and only use the third column as the sort key. Since this will leave the line with the first found instance of the sort key but discard the lines with duplicated sort keys (and with lower values in the fourth column, thanks to the *first* sort), it will give us the wanted result.

This approach disregards the contents of the first two columns completely.

Comment: much appreciate you it is working as I want

Comment: @Ali If one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
awk '$4>n[$3]{n[$3]=$4;l[$3]=$0}END{for(i in l)print l[i]}' file_a file_b > file_c
```

Explanation: if 4th column is greater than remembered maximum for the same 3rd column (in `n` array), then remember the new 4th column and the whole line (in `l` array) for that 3rd column. At the end print all remembered lines.

Comment: many thanks for you. it is working as I want

Answer (score 0):

If your awk interpreter resides in /usr/bin/:

`cat doit.awk`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

NF!=4 {

    print "Field number must be 4" > "/dev/stderr";
    exit 1;
}

FILENAME=="file_a" {

    i++;
    numval_a[i]=$4;
    letters_a[i]=$1FS$2FS$3;
}

FILENAME=="file_b" {

    k++;
    numval_b[k]=$4;
    letters_b[k]=$1FS$2FS$3;
}

END {

    for(j=1; j<=i; j++) {

        if(letters_a[j]!=letters_b[j]) {

            print "Line missmatch!" > "/dev/stderr";
            exit 2;
        }

        if(numval_a[j]>numval_b[j])
            max=numval_a[j];
        else
            max=numval_b[j];

        print letters_a[j], max;
    }
}
```

`awk -f doit.awk file_a file_b`

```
a b c 10
d e f 15
g h i 20
j k l 25
```

Comment: I did not check it is complicated for me. thanks for your time I really appreciate you

Comment: hardcoding filenames in the script limits its usability a lot